# How to summarize projects' time in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I want to summarize the time spent on tasks during the week to weekly goals.

Here is a sample sheet. 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11WL3_LpSBdUOjvonW18CqBpyDPu-ACt3ZOc2QW-oQhI/edit#gid=0

I have weekly goals (in R1), and tasks that I do to work towards those goals (R7 and R11). Each task has a project/goal associated with it (day row + 1), and how much time I spent on it (day row + 2). I would like to summarize the time spent on each project (R2 and R3) or simply R4. Ideally, also get the summary of all tasks as in R5.

Just to explain a couple of examples:

- R5,Column:C (C5) is all the tasks that I did towards goal 2 (C7, C11, D11 because the next row for these cells have `wg2` (goal 2) in them).
- The same logic applies to times.

In particular, I would like to fill the cells B2:D5 programmatically. I can make R8 and R12 as dropdown whose valid values are taken from R1.

I can easily do this in python or such, but I am trying to keep it simple and do this all in the spreadsheet.

I will appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF($E2="Total", 
 SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2, COLUMN())&":"&ADDRESS(ROW()-1, COLUMN()))), 
 SUM(IF(($B$8:$E$27=B$1)*(INDEX(SPLIT(VLOOKUP(ROW($A$7:$A$26), 
 IF($A$7:$A$26<>"",{ROW($A$7:$A$26), $A$7:$A$26}), 2, 1), " "),,1)=$E2), 
 $B$9:$E$28, ))))
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1veOKlvvoo_RQ2t6NDIQnQSYUpPG5ga_jrC06JNY0lmo/edit#gid=0)

Comment: This is AMAZING. Thanks @player0 for your help. Not even help, you pretty much gave the solution. It took me a few hours to unpack it, as I have not done google sheet scripting. I REALLY APPRECIATE your time!